# Alternative to exFAT, R/W Operations MacOS & Windows, Performance Test

Tags: windows-10, performance, filesystems, macos-sierra, exfat

I was reading that **exFAT** is most compatible File System: https://www.howtogeek.com/73178/what-file-system-should-i-use-for-my-usb-drive/

I test it and for me **exFAT** is very, very slow!!!!

Some Question has 7/8 years old:

[What is a file system which has r/w on all major OSes](https://superuser.com/questions/105485/what-is-a-file-system-which-has-r-w-on-all-major-oses) (2010)

[Cross-platform file system](https://superuser.com/questions/45130/cross-platform-file-system) (2009)

1. Some **RECENT (2017)** alternative File System for **mac OS Sierra** and **Windows 10**?
2. Is there a File System Compatibility List:

   - for **Windows 10**?
   - for **mac OS Sierra**?
3. Is there some Read & Write performance Test of HFS+ for macOS, NTFS for Windows and exFAT for macOS/Windows?

**NOTE**: *Test copy Results*

```
PreschoolNumbers.app / 730 files, 21.1MB/21.148.590 Bytes

Copy Process
From     To      Time
ExFAT    NTFS    1:13
ExFAT    ExFAT   1:13
NTFS     NTFS    3:10 (Incredible!)
```

Comment: exFat is the only choice, that doesn't require third-party drivers either on OS c or Windows.

Comment: I was testing the 15.0.293 version of Paragon NTFS for MAC and the speed is very low too...

Comment: Maybe you just have a very slow drive?

Comment: I have a AHD710-1TU3, is's a USB 3.0, I Have a MacBook Air (13-inch, Early 2015).  I'm using terminal: `mv ` command.