# File system format for both windows and linux use (besides fat32)

Tags: windows, linux, filesystems, compatibility, format

I'm looking for a file system to format my large external drive with that can read/write in linux and read/write in windows.  I know Fat32 is usually the best suggestion, but a large percent of my files are >4GB, so Fat32 won't work.  Are there any other ones out there that I can get to work?

Thanks

Comment: UDF works now http://serverfault.com/q/55089/105363

Comment: There are now several duplicates of this question, including this one: http://superuser.com/questions/45130/cross-platform-file-system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NTFS. Works natively in Windows, and well in Linux/OS X via NTFS-3g.