# What kind of file system which can be read by MacOS X, Linux and Windows?

Tags: windows, linux, macos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Cross-platform file system](https://superuser.com/questions/45130/cross-platform-file-system)

Can you please tell me what kind of file system can be read by MacOS X, Linux and Windows?
And it can create a file greater 4 GB?

Comment: duplicate of [this](http://superuser.com/questions/225560/what-filesystem-to-use-when-using-both-windows-and-linux), [this](http://superuser.com/questions/221754/file-system-format-for-both-windows-and-linux-use-besides-fat32), [this](http://superuser.com/questions/105485/what-is-a-file-system-which-has-r-w-on-all-major-oses), [this](http://superuser.com/questions/235753/filesystem-to-use-for-external-hard-drive-to-be-used-with-mac-linux-and-windows), ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NTFS is probably your best bet.

Answer (score 2):

NTFS, but it requires the NTFS-3G driver in Linux and OSX.

Take a gander at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems

Comment: Partially wrong. You don't need a driver to read NTFS in OS X. And the (free) NTFS implementations for OS X (e.g. via fuse) are quite slow when writing.