# Cross platform Hard Disk encryption?

Tags: hard-drive, filesystems, encryption, cross-platform

I would like to encrypt my hard drive so that it requires a password to access it. However features like BitLocker in Windows will only work under Windows, and cannot be accessed from another OS such as  Ubuntu or Mac OS X.

How can I create a cross-platform encrypted file system?

Comment: Related - once you have the HDD encrypted, don't forget that you'll need a [cross platform file system](http://superuser.com/questions/45130/cross-platform-file-system) running on it as well.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[TrueCrypt](http://www.truecrypt.org/) is cross platform.

> TrueCrypt currently supports the
>   following operating systems:
>
> Windows 7
>   Windows 7 64-bit
>   Windows Vista
>   Windows Vista 64-bit
>   Windows XP
>   Windows XP 64-bit
>   Windows Server 2008
>   Windows Server 2008 64-bit
>   Windows Server 2003
>   Windows Server 2003 64-bit
>   Windows 2000 SP4
>
> Mac OS X 10.6 Snow Leopard (32-bit)
>   Mac OS X 10.5 Leopard
>   Mac OS X 10.4 Tiger
>
> Linux (32-bit and 64-bit versions, kernel 2.4, 2.6 or compatible)

Comment: It also supports Mac OS X 10.6 64-bit, but you need to find a beta MacFUSE version. I found it somewhere on StackOverflow or maybe here.

Comment: @kizzx2, I dont understand what you meant MacFUSE. Care to explain a little.

Comment: @Starx If you have actually gone and installed TrueCrypt on MacOS X. You'll understand. Try creating a new encrypted partition. If it succeeds, it's all good and you don't have to worry about it. If it fails, it will be prominent (something about MacFUSE). The reason is because the default MacFUSE installed by TrueCrypt is not compatible with the latest Mac OS X. You need to find an updated, unofficial version somewhere, but I forgot where :( You can probably Google "macfuse truecrypt os x beta" to find it.

Comment: As of 5-2014, TrueCrypt is no longer being maintained and the creator is actively discouraging its use.

Comment: @txyoji [CipherShed](https://www.ciphershed.org/) claims they are continuing on with development of TrueCrypt.  They have a [new release v0.7.4.0](https://www.ciphershed.org/download/), but so far, only for Windows.