# How to encrypt an entire Disk with full cross platform access?

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, encryption, truecrypt

I would like to encrypt an external USB Hard Drive in manner that allows full access (read+write) from Ubuntu trusty, Windows 8 and optionally Android and older Windows versions. With TrueCrypt development (as suggested by as an answer to this Question: [Cross platform Hard Disk encryption?](https://superuser.com/questions/285638/cross-platform-hard-disk-encryption) ) being in an uncertain state ( http://truecrypt.sourceforge.net/ ), what alternatives are there which are still in deveopment

Comment: We are not able to provide product recomendations on this website.  The status of Truecrypt is being over reported.  `Truecrypt 7.1a` didn't stop being secure just because it was EOL'ed.  The sad truth is Truecrupt really was one of the very few solutions that were supported across all major platforms.

Comment: Just because the answer on that question doesn't meet your needs, doesn't mean it's a different question.  If you'd like newer/updated answers for the existing question, [place a bounty on it](http://superuser.com/help/bounty) and post a comment explaining why you're putting a bounty on it.