# How to make rsync copy actual data instead of symlinks?

Tags: linux, rsync

In the source directory I have some symbolic links. These links point to some paths and data is present in those paths also; but using `rsync` it is copying only the link files, not the data that is present in the path.

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 lafter lafter   58 Sep 26 16:57 8770 -> ../../../../.sites_repository/brest/8770/3.2.08.05.b-b0001
lrwxrwxrwx 1 lafter lafter   59 Sep 26 16:57 bootdvd -> ../../../../.sites_repository/colombes/bootdvd/12.1.013.000
```

Any solutions?

Comment: Try it with the explicit paths rather than the dotted back path or whatever and see what result you get for a simple test.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [rsync and symbolic links](https://superuser.com/questions/799354/rsync-and-symbolic-links)

Answer (score 58):

`man rsync` says:

```
-L, --copy-links    transform symlink into referent file/dir
```

Comment: Thanks. This copied the symbolic links target's content.

Comment: macOS As soon -r is involved, it seems not to work.

Comment: Works for me. What exacly doesn't work (expected/actual result)?

Comment: In a rsync -rL command the alias of a .mkv file transfers only 3K of the original 2.1MB

Comment: Looks like a very different problem. I would expect either a full copy or nothing at all. Could be a totally unrelated cause... Otherwise it's a bug.