# Convert NTFS partition to ext4 - How to copy the data?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, ntfs, ext4

I wanted to convert my `D:\` partition with all my data from NTFS to ext4 and the internet told me that I should do the following:

1. Shrink all partitions to a minimum size
2. Back up my data (done by cloning the partition in GParted)
3. Format the partition to ext4 (Not done yet, but not that hard)
4. Copy the backup to the drive
5. Delete backup and grow all partitions

And I don't know how to do part 4. Can I really copy a whole drive like I would do for folders? Are there tools specialized in this? How can I make sure I don't miss any folders hidden by the system or symbolic links etc.? I have an Ubuntu live USB-Stick to work from if that is important.

Comment: You don’t know how to copy files?

Comment: I do know how to copy files. The question is about if I can copy whole drives like I do for files or if there are special things to take care of to not break the system.

Comment: There are tools that read each sector of a drive and outputs an image of said drive.

Comment: So you're all going to do this using one single drive? Hope you have a backup.

Answer (score 9):

### 1. FreeFileSync GUI tool (Windows, Mac, Linux)

To ensure you don't miss any data, I highly highly recommend using a good file-copy tool like [FreeFileSync](https://freefilesync.org/). It is graphical, no cost, free and open source, and cross-platform (Windows, Mac, Linux). Just be sure not to screw it up and copy backwards, deleting everything! That's not hard to get right, however, since it's graphical and very user-friendly.

Just set up your folders with *source* on the left and *destination* on the right, then click the gear at the top right and choose the "Mirror" option to mirror from left to right, then press the "Compare" button at the top left. Once it determines what it needs to copy, it will pop up an info screen showing what it's going to do (how many files it will create, overwrite, or delete, etc.). Ensure you see nothing next to the trash can (indicating what is to be deleted), or that you see *expected* files to be deleted, as marked with the trash can and a minus sign, and then press the "Synchronize" button to begin. Voila! Easy to use. Here's a screenshot: [image]

### 2. rsync Command-line tool (Linux, Windows with Cygwin) (AKA: "How to use rsync"):

If you are doing the copy from Linux, you may also use FreeFileSync of course, but if your'e a command-line guru you might like [`rsync`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) better. It's a command-line-only tool, and harder to use, but still very powerful, albeit not quite as powerful as FreeFileSync since it doesn't handle two-way syncing very well. Here's a few of my favorite `rsync` commands:

1. COPY from source to destination, leaving anything in the destination that isn't conflicting still intact:

   ```
    sudo rsync -rah --stats --info=progress2 '/path/to/source' '/path/to/destination'
   ```

   Optionally, add `--verbose`, or just `-v` (or `-rahv` in my case) to also get a full list of exactly what will be copied.

   Optionally, add `--dry-run` to show what *would* happen but NOT ACTUALLY DO IT YET.

   Optionally, you may also log the entire list of files to be copied to a `stdout.log` file like this, and any errors to a `stderr.log` file like this. Here I remove the progress indicator by removing `--info=progress2`, just so the log files don't get polluted with progress info everywhere:

   ```
    (sudo rsync -rah --verbose --dry-run --stats '/path/to/source' '/path/to/destination' | tee -a '/path/to/stdout.log') 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 | tee -a '/path/to/stderr.log'
   ```

   Remove `--dry-run` from the above when ready to actually make the copy. Be sure to review the stats paragraph printout (which printed because you had `--stats`) at the end of the **stdout.log** file before running the script for real, to make sure it all looks good.

   Here's an example of a `--stats` output obtained from doing the MIRROR option below. Notice it is deleting some files. Pay careful attention to that, as deleting files can't be undone (at least not without special software recovery tools). Just keep in mind it is *permanently deleting them*, NOT sending them to some sort of recycle bin or something, so watch out!

   > Number of files: 102,033 (reg: 89,638, dir: 9,867, link: 2,502, special: 26)
   > Number of created files: 3 (reg: 3)
   > Number of deleted files: 9,861 (reg: 9,360, dir: 474, link: 27)
   > Number of regular files transferred: 25
   > Total file size: 8.12G bytes
   > Total transferred file size: 35.30M bytes
   > Literal data: 35.30M bytes
   > Matched data: 0 bytes
   > File list size: 917.43K
   > File list generation time: 0.007 seconds
   > File list transfer time: 0.000 seconds
   > Total bytes sent: 38.33M
   > Total bytes received: 1.02M
   >
   > sent 38.33M bytes  received 1.02M bytes  7.15M bytes/sec
   > total size is 8.12G  speedup is 206.37
2. To MIRROR from source to destination, which means also *deleting* anything in destination that is *not in* source (notice the "Number of deleted files" line in the stats output shown just above), add `--delete --delete-excluded` (even though we aren't excluding anything yet, once you learn about the `--exclude=PATTERN` syntax you'll also realize you want the `--delete-excluded` flag).

   First, the *safe* dry-run version:

   ```
    (sudo rsync -rah --verbose --dry-run --stats --delete --delete-excluded '/path/to/source' '/path/to/destination' | tee -a '/path/to/stdout.log') 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 | tee -a '/path/to/stderr.log'
   ```

   And now the *danger danger danger--could delete everything if you do source and destination backwards* version (so check the stats output at the end of stdout.log before continuing):

   ```
    (sudo rsync -rah --verbose --stats --delete --delete-excluded '/path/to/source' '/path/to/destination' | tee -a '/path/to/stdout.log') 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 | tee -a '/path/to/stderr.log'
   ```

   And now the version that doesn't save to any log files in case you want to just *see the live progress* and the stats paragraph at the end, but NOT have a log of individual files copied or deleted in stdout.log, or errors printed in stderr.log:

   ```
    sudo rsync -rah --info=progress2 --stats --delete --delete-excluded '/path/to/source' '/path/to/destination'
   ```
3. And this is just the beginning of rsync. Read the manual: `man rsync`, or online: https://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync, and keep in mind you can mix and match many of the options I've shown above. Other really useful things to look into include setting up a **source.txt** file, and an **exclude.txt** file, to include and exclude, respectively, lists of files and paths. Do this with the option `--files-from='/path/to/source.txt'` and `--exclude-from='/path/to/exclude.txt'`, respectively. This is extremely useful. Lastly, this goes really well with the `--relative` option. In the end, a full Bash script might look something like this:

   ```
     (sudo rsync $OPTIONS $SRC $DEST | tee -a $LOG_STDOUT) 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 | tee -a $LOG_STDERR
   ```

   ...where `$SRC` is your source path (in this case, a *relative* path for all files in the **source.txt** file, such as simply `/` to make everything relative to your root directory), `$DEST` is your destination path, `$LOG_STDOUT` is your path to where you'd like to log your stdout info, `$LOG_STDERR` is your path to where you'd like to log your stderr info, and `$OPTIONS` might look something like this:

   ```
    -rah --verbose --stats --relative --info=progress2 --delete --delete-excluded --dry-run --files-from='/path/to/source.txt' --exclude-from='/path/to/exclude.txt'
   ```

   And, of course, as stated above, you might want to remove `--verbose`, `--relative`, `--info=progress2`, `--delete` and `--delete-excluded`, and `--dry-run`, as desired, depending on what you're doing.

### Important: for exFAT and FAT filesystems, where you want to use `rsync`...

See also my answer here: [Best settings for using rsync with FAT and exFAT filesystems](https://superuser.com/a/1785111/425838)

### See also:

1. [my Q&A] [How to install FreeFileSync on an Ubuntu Live USB installation disk](https://askubuntu.com/a/1468171/327339)
2. [my answer] [Ask Ubuntu: How to show the transfer progress and speed when copying files with cp?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1275972/327339)
3. [my answer] [Unix & Linux: Is it possible to see cp speed and percent copied?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/567828/114401)
4. [my answer] [Ask Ubuntu: How to change permission of a drive in an external hard disk?](https://askubuntu.com/a/1302532/327339)

Comment: I just tried FreeFileSync based on this answer and it works really well for my use-cases (mirroring and synching directories with over 1 million files each.

Comment: -r is redundant as -a already means -rlptgoD.

Comment: @Dagelf, no, that's not _always_ true. From `man rsync`, under the **--files-from=FILE** section: **"The  --archive  (-a) option’s behavior does not imply --recursive (-r), so specify it explicitly, if you want it."** So, since my last example uses the `--files-from` option, and it's better to be safe than sorry, just get in the habit of explicitly declaring `-r` even when you use `-a`.

Comment: Under normal circumstances, though, yes, you are right. `man rsync` says: `-a, --archive     archive mode; equals -rlptgoD (no -H,-A,-X)`.

Comment: `rsync` is such a tricky beast I have learned to just be as explicit as possible _all the time._

Comment: Note also under the `--archive` section of `man rsync`, it states that `-r` is not always implied, in these words (with my additions in square brackets): _"The only exception to the above equivalence [referring to `-a` being equivalent to `-rlptgoD`] is when `--files-from` is specified, in which case `-r` is not implied."_

Comment: your redirects for stdout and stderr are incorrect - both log files will have the exact same contents, so I'm not really sure what's the purpose of all those pipes

Comment: @SergioLeone, have you tried running it? In `(sudo rsync $OPTIONS $SRC $DEST | tee -a $LOG_STDOUT) 3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 | tee -a $LOG_STDERR`, the `LOG_STDOUT` file will contain only the stdout, as desired, and the `LOG_STDERR` file will contain only the stderr content, as desired. The purpose of piping to `tee` is to get all of that information still into the main terminal, however, to see live, rather than just into the files.

Comment: Explanation: a pipe (`|`) only connects stdout of one process to stdin of another. It does _not_ forward stderr. Therefore, the `| tee -a $LOG_STDOUT` part logs only stdout to the file, because that's how piping to `tee` works. And, the `| tee -a $LOG_STDERR` part also logs only stdout to the file, _except_ that stdout is actually stderr now in that case, because `3>&1 1>&2 2>&3` swaps the stderr and stdout streams. Note that the parenthesis in the Bash command are also really important for command grouping to make this all work. So, as I have it is correct, and each file works as intended.

Comment: Reminder for anyone trying to understand this: file descriptor `0` = stdin, `1` = stdout, `2` = stderr. `3` in this case is like a placeholder variable, in the form of a file descriptor, to allow the swapping/redirect of stdout and stderr so that stdout becomes stderr, and stderr becomes stdout, so that I pipe the right thing to the LOG_STDERR via `3>&1 1>&2 2>&3 | tee -a $LOG_STDERR`.

Comment: @GabrielStaples, yes I have tried running it (on ubuntu 22.04 if that matters), and I see both log files have same size after rsync finishes. I would post the results here, but comments are limited by size and don't support multi-line code blocks, so the output would not be very useful.

Comment: @SergioLeone, sounds like I'm mistaken. I'll take a closer look when I get a chance.