# Cross-OS Storage

Tags: linux, windows, android, storage

I want to set up a storage server for my home. I use many devices with a range of operating systems.

I am wondering if it is possible to set it up in a way such that I'd be able to access it from all of my devices on the LAN seamlessly as if it was a part of their system. For example in windows it would appear as another disk, in linux it would be just another directory, wherever I mount it. I would like to go a step further and have it available for android as well. This sounds like something impossible to me, but is it?

Comment: There are multiple file systems supported by multiple operating systems, which OSs you wish to use will direct you to which file systems can be used.

Comment: SMB/CIFS works natively on Windows, is supported with Samba under Linux, and there are even Android clients. Of course it will match Windows best.

Comment: You would probably also need to set up some kind of auto-mount for the drives on boot, but take a look here: http://superuser.com/questions/45130/cross-platform-file-system?rq=1 for more info on different File Systems for cross platform.  Not sure if this is a really a duplicate of that question but has some good info you might find useful

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you're just creating a NAS for your local network.  You can export filesystems via NFS and CIFS (to pick the two most obvious protocols).
That means that the answer to your question is **Yes, you can**.