# i'm i am trying to make dual disk windows and linux setup. and dont know how to do it

Tags: windows-7, linux, hard-drive, partitioning

hello so it may sound confusing but listen what i am trying to make

so i now have windows and linux on the same disk switching in grub menu

and i am trying to make same thing except the OSs will be on one disk (160gb) linux and windows

while on the other (1TB) there will be all the data both on linux and windows

i dont know how do i make it ?do i need to make seperate partition on both disks ? or just the one where OSes are and while installing windows would it choose the correct disk ?

Answer (score 0):

I would disconnect the large disk and install Windows and Linux to separate partitions on the smaller one. **This way neither OS would install anything on the other disk for sure. This is like your current setup.** Then, only after OS-es are set, I would connect the large disk that is supposed to hold non-system data.

You may create one or more partitions on this extra disk. Ask yourself what filesystem(s) you need:

- Linux filesystems like `ext4` or `btrfs` support Linux-type file permissions and attributes; they may be supported in Windows with 3rd party programs but I wouldn't expect much.
- Windows filesystems like `NTFS` or `exFAT` can be used with Linux; common implementations work in userspace (not as fast as kernelspace); these filesystems don't support Linux-type file permissions.
- `FAT32` is quite universal but inadequate for large partitions nor large files; it doesn't support file permissions at all.

Read [this question about cross-platform filesystems](https://superuser.com/q/45130/432690).

I would use `NTFS` for common (shared) storage. If you need Linux to store additional data on Linux filesystem then make it a separate partition.

After you partition the large drive and create filesystem(s) you should assign drive letter(s) in Windows and add entry (entries) to `/etc/fstab` in Linux.