# How do you make Windows 7 fully case-sensitive with respect to the filesystem?

Tags: windows-7, windows, filesystems, ntfs

I want to make Windows 7 case-sensitive when it reads/writes anything on the hard drive (the C drive, or any other NTFS drive).

I found a video via google that says to change the registry key

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\DontPrettyPath
```

to a value of 1 ([source](http://www.wonderhowto.com/how-to-make-filenames-case-sensitive-windows-and-linux-127204/)).

I also found a Windows support item that says something about modifying the registry key

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\kernel\obcaseinsensitive
```

that leads me to assume putting a value of 0 will make Windows case-sensitive with NTFS filesystems ([source](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929110)).

I have a feeling the second solution is the answer, but I'm not sure and I don't want to try it without being sure.

Does anyone know for sure what is the correct way to make Windows 7 case-sensitive when it reads/writes to the C drive (and any other NTFS drive)?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can set the `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\kernel\ dword:ObCaseInsensitive` registry value to `0` as other authors suggested.  Create a file named `add.reg` with the following content and run it.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\kernel]
"obcaseinsensitive"=dword:00000000
```

Then use *Cygwin* to work with case-sensitive filenames.

In order to do so, you need to mount NTFS filesystems with `posix=1` option in your `/etc/fstab`, as [this article](https://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-specialnames.html#pathnames-casesensitive) suggests. Here's a snippet from my `fstab`:

```
none                    /cygdrive       cygdrive        binary,posix=1,user             0 0
C:                      /cygdrive/c     ntfs            binary,posix=1,user,auto        0 0
C:/Users                /home           ntfs            binary,posix=1,user,auto        0 0
```

Once the above is done, you'll be able to deal with case-sensitive filenames using `bash`, `mc`, `git` etc.

Comment: You must restart for this to take effect.

Comment: @William: I believe you only need to terminate all *Cygwin* processes and services (like *Apache*, *sshd*, etc.). That should be enough, as `cygwin1.dll` will be unloaded from RAM.

Comment: I'm talking about `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\kernel\ dword:ObCaseInsensitive`  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/929110

Comment: Thanks so much for the `posix=1` info.

Comment: cygwin??? I don't see cygwin mentioned anywhere in the question!

Answer (score 21):

All these settings that you can find on the web are for **NFS** not for **NTFS** (note the difference)!

NFS (Network File System) is a network protocol.

Thus changing the registry key `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\kernel\obcaseinsensitive` **WILL NOT** change anything you want.

**NTFS is case-sensitive** but **Windows API is NOT**, it only remembers the filename case. This mean that despite your file is displayed as `AbC.TXT` it is still accessible by `abc.txt` and `aBc.TxT`. This is a limitation of Windows, not NTFS.

The other one `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced\DontPrettyPath` basically turns off the normalization of legacy 8.3 filenames used by DOS (which are all caps). When it is turned on (default) `ABC.TXT` will be displayed as `Abc.txt`, but still be accessible by all other variations.

**To be more accurate:**

Actually it depends of the software that accesses the FS.

If it uses WIN32 API (which 99.9% of the software does) it will be case-insensitive whatever you do. All built-in software in Windows (like Explorer, command prompt, Internet Explorer and etc.) and all consumer software out there uses WIN32 and is always case-insensitive.

NFS Service, Java and some others are POSIX and they will obey the 'obcaseinsensitive' registry setting. However turning off the option might actually get you bigger problems, because this software can create files that are not accesible from Windows itself and other Win32 software.

Comment: Actually, on a FS level before additional processing it IS case sensitive, however, NTFS translates all file names to all uppercase and when one with lowercase characters is entered translates it to uppercase then looks for said file.(see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/103657)

Comment: You are right. I just tried to explain it simpler.

Comment: So how does a Win32 based version of java succeed in finding "SHORT.class" vs. "Short.class" if they are in the same directory?  I cannot believe there is NO call to do this.

Comment: I think because Java is POSIX

Comment: I edited your question to be more cohesive/accurate but you are welcome to revert the changes.

Comment: I'm fairly sure that the standard Java runtime (i.e., from Oracle) is **not** case-insensitive on Windows.  If you tried to put `SHORT.class` and `Short.class` in the same directory, it wouldn't work.  (Of course if they are inside a .jar file there's no problem.)

Answer (score 16):

In order to actually create 2 files with the same name but different case in the same directory, you need to install Unix Services 3.5 but this only works on 32 bit Windows. Then you need to run "C Shell" to create the files. You can't create the files through explorer. Once created, explorer doesn't play nice with the files. If you go to rename the second one, the cursor jumps to the first one. Also, most applications can only open one of the files, as they expect a case-insensitive file system.  If you are on 64 bit install Cygwin and change it to case sensitive.

I was trying to emulate a Linux case-sensitive file-system for debugging purposes during development. It seems the better approach is to use VMWare with an instance of Ubuntu for development.

Comment: "use VMWare with an instance of Ubuntu for development" => Not the case with games

Answer (score 4):

I think this is what you're looking for:

http://www.chilkatsoft.com/p/p_454.asp

This page recommends setting `HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\kernel\ dword:ObCaseInsensitive` to 0 to make it case-sensitive.  I think you found this already though, and this looks like the standard way to do it (even the Microsoft KB you found suggests it).

It looks like you have to change kernel settings.  Beware of updates though.

EDIT: Watch out though, some programs might depend on case insensitivity.

EDIT: You could probably use a UDF partition.  This filesystem is case-sensitive and I think it works on both Windows and Linux.

See [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee681827(v=vs.85).aspx) and [this](https://superuser.com/questions/150864/driver-for-writing-to-udf-partitions-from-windows-xp).

Comment: Can you post more information from the page you link to please. Don't copy the whole thing but you can copy the relevant paragraph and summarise the rest.

Comment: Well, the whole page only is a paragraph.  I'll make a quick edit though.

Comment: Thanks tjameson. Regarding programs that might depend on case insensitivity, this is indeed a big problem. A program might look for "WINDOWS" and not find it because it is really "Windows" now, right? Shoot, I'm at a loss trying to figure out how to copy things over from Linux to Windows, and I've found myself in a situation where folders of the same spelling with different caps exist in one location.

Comment: Well, the only thing I can think of is to conflicts manually.  If you copy files over, Windows should ask you if you want to merge or make a copy or something.  I can't remember (I'm a linux man myself).

Comment: According to this [article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/817921) this only works for non-Win32 subsystems, so doesn't apply to NTFS.

Comment: I added an option for UDF.  This will circumvent the problem.

Comment: The question was for NTFS.

Comment: @harrymc Yeah, I understand that, but I left it as an option.  My answer says how to do it in NTFS, but using a separate UDF partition may also be a viable solution...

Comment: Thanks for those EDITS tjameson. That stuff about UDF is interesting. I wonder if any apps that encounter problem with case-sensitivity turned on will also face the same problem in Windows with UDF?

Answer (score 4):

What Microsoft has to say about NTFS and changing case sensitivity.

Looks like you do not have to change the kernel to allow case sensitive lookups on the network.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc783185(WS.10).aspx

.

Configuring case sensitivity for file and folder names

> Applies To: Windows Server 2003 R2
>
> To configure case sensitivity for file and folder names using the Windows interface
>   Open Microsoft Services for Network File System: click Start, point to Programs, point to Administrative Tools, and then click Microsoft Services for Network File System.
>
> If necessary, connect to the computer you want to manage.
>
> Right-click Server for NFS, and then click Properties.
>
> Click the Filename Handling tab.
>
> Do one of the following:
>
> To enable case-sensitive file and directory name lookups, select the Enable case sensitive lookups check box.
>
> To disable case-sensitive file and directory name lookups, clear the Enable case sensitive lookups check box.
>
> Click Apply.
>
> Important
>   These changes will not take effect until Server for NFS is restarted. For information about how to stop and start Server for NFS, see Starting and stopping Server for NFS.
>   You also need to disable Windows kernel case-insensitivity in order for Server for NFS to support case-sensitive file names. You can disable Windows kernel case-insensitivity by clearing the following registry key to 0:
>   HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\kernel
>   DWORD “obcaseinsensitive”

To configure case sensitivity for file and folder names using the command line
Open the command prompt.

> To enable case sensitivity, type the following:
>
> nfsadmin server [ ComputerName ] config casesensitivelookups=yes
>
> To disable case sensitivity and optionally specify the case of file names returned by Server for NFS, at a command prompt, type the following:
>
> nfsadmin server [ ComputerName ] config casesensitivelookups=no [ntfscase={upper | lower | preserve}]
>
> Argument > Computer Name = The name of the computer you want to configure.
>
> Important
>   These changes will not take effect until Server for NFS is restarted. For information about how to stop and start Server for NFS, see Starting and stopping Server for NFS.
>
> Note
>   The ntfscase option sets the case sensitivity for the NTFS file system. The default case sensitivity is preserve (preserve case).
>   To view the complete syntax for this command, at a command prompt, type:
>   nfsadmin server /?

.

Comment: I dan't think this allows for having multiple files with the same name, which is what he wants to do.

Comment: Then he will have to do the registry hack.

Comment: Applies To: Windows Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 3):

Microsoft [states](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/100108) ;

> In NTFS, names preserve case, but are
>   not case sensitive. 
> NTFS makes no
>   distinction of filenames based on
>   case.

Allowing case-sensitivity under Windows would allow malware to create
files that the user can't access or delete, so it is not allowed for a good reason.

In any case, I am quite sure that if you managed to make NTFS case-sensitive,
Windows will crash and re-installation will be the only solution.

Comment: You are also correct that it presents a security issue if you do.      "For example, a version of edit.exe infected with a Trojan horse-type malicious program, and named EDIT.EXE, could be stored in the same directory as edit.exe. If a user were to type edit at a Windows command prompt, the Trojan horse version (EDIT.EXE) could be executed instead of the standard version"..http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732389.aspx

Comment: It probably won't crash Windows unless you rename key files/folders.  I'm pretty sure that Windows makes sure to use the correct case, in fact, they even recommend it.

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting tjameson. Can you provide a link to that recommendation?

Comment: If malware gets write access to your disk, you have big problems whether your filesystem is case sensitive or not. #redherring

Comment: @tjameson have you ever loaded Safe mode and watched the files? Defiantly not proper case for all of them.

Comment: The Registry is chock-full of references to system files with wildly inconsistent case usage. Case-sensitivity would cause massive breakage.

Comment: According to [Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/100625), "Filenames are Case Sensitive on NTFS Volumes"

Comment: @niutech: This article is about Windows NT 3.1, and only says that an application can use case insensitivity. Of course nobody uses it, except as Microsoft did - in POSIX compliance tests.

Comment: it's not correct. For example you can create files differed only in case in Ubuntu and Windows can still work without crashing https://superuser.com/q/1116625/241386

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: Bash on Ubuntu on Windows is a special case. From your link: "You can't access to those folders in Explorer, simply because the Win32 subsystem doesn't support case sensitivity, and Explorer doesn't support POSIX subsystem".

Comment: but what you said `I am quite sure that if you managed to make NTFS case-sensitive, Windows will crash and re-installation will be the only solution` is completely incorrect. First, NTFS already supports case sensitive and nothing else needs to be done. Windows support is another problem. MS has said `POSIX Support: NTFS is the most POSIX.1 compliant of the supported file systems because it supports the following POSIX.1 requirements: Case Sensitive Naming:` in your link above. Second, no crash will happen even when there are files with same case-insensitive name

Comment: you don't even need Ubuntu on Windows to work with case-sensitive files. Windows supported POSIX subsystem decades ago, and applications that are carefully designed can work with those files without problem

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: With all respect, you don't know Windows API and disk tables well enough.

Comment: yes, I'm not proficient in Windows API but I know that "NTFS, names preserve case, but are not case sensitive" is wrong, and "Windows will crash and re-installation will be the only solution" is also wrong

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: Let's say that our knowledge differs, but mine is based on experience. Bash etc. on Windows just simulates case-sensitive, as Windows is not built to do that.