# why mounted vfat volume is case sensitive partially?

Tags: linux, mount, vfat

I have strange observation.
I mounted vfat filesystem like this:

`mount -t vfat -o loop vfat.vol mnt`

I expected it would be case insensitive.
And it is as long as file name length is no longer than 8!
I can't create two different files: x1234567 and X1234567, but I can
create x12345678 and X12345678 ! It is 100% reproductible with simple
echo "abc" >filename command.
What is going on here? How to make fat volume 100% case insensitive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because file names longer than 8 characters are not supported by FAT directly, but via [LFN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_filename) extension. FAT is indeed case-insensitive, that's why you can't create `x1234567` and `X1234567` files. However, when you create files with long names, short file names are created instead, plus an LFN entry which holds the full name.

So when you create files `x12345678` and `X12345678`, these files are given short names like `X12345~1` and `X12345~2`, which are valid and different FAT names. Linux has a relaxed attitude towards checking the uniqueness of LFN entries, so you end up creating two entries which are differentiated only by case; something Windows wouldn't allow. But this is a limitation (or rather a feature) of Windows, not the FAT file system.

Sidenote: I bet you can also create a file named `CON` in linux on a FAT volume.

See [vfat documentation](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/vfat.txt) for mount options which define how linux should work with file names.

Comment: Ok, so I consider it a bug in linux driver. Thanks.

Comment: Windows has supported case-sensitive files for decades. See [How do you make Windows 7 fully case-sensitive with respect to the filesystem?](https://superuser.com/q/266110/241386). It's just that the Win32 namespace doesn't allow case-sensitivity. And you can create a file or folder named `CON` in Windows (or any reserved words like AUX, NUL, PRN...) by [adding the \\.\ or \\?\ prefix](https://superuser.com/q/86999/241386)