# How can I access case-sensitive paths on Windows (created with Bash-on-Ubuntu-on-Windows)?

Tags: windows-10, bash, windows-explorer, filesystems, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Bash-on-Ubuntu-on-Windows supports case-sensitive file paths. This means that I can create two files or directories with names only differing in capitalization. I have issues accessing those files, though.

Running

```
bash -c "touch Magic ; mkdir magic ; echo Secret! > magic/secret"
```

Creates a file names `Magic`, a directory named `magic` and a file names `secret` in that directory.

`bash -c "ls -lR"` yields

```
.:
total 0
drwxrwxrwx 2 root root 0 Aug 23 10:37 magic
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 0 Aug 23 10:37 Magic

./magic:
total 0
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 8 Aug 23 10:37 secret
```

(I am not sure why I get `root`, as it is not the default user, but that does not seem relevant to my question.)

Windows Explorer shows:
[image: Windows Explorer shows file and directory]

Now, while `bash` can easily access the `magic/secret` file in the directory, Windows seems to treat both the directory and the file as one and the same. So double-clicking the directory I get a "directory name invalid" error
[image: Error dbl-clicking directory]

Same goes for using `cd`, as I get `The directory name is invalid.` printed out.

Is there any way (other than using Bash) to access the `magic/secret` file?

### Partial Answer

I've found a way to do it programmatically, with some registry changes. Described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39095594/windows-api-to-access-case-sensitive-paths-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows/39116635#39116635). But it seems that there is no way to do it with existing Windows tooling.

Comment: Did you try a third party file explorer like Total Commander and/or PowerShell?

Comment: No, I did not. Bu I don't think anything works without the registry change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't access to those folders in Explorer, simply because the Win32 subsystem doesn't support case sensitivity, and Explorer doesn't support POSIX subsystem

> ## Build 14361
>
> For general Windows information on build 14361 visit the Windows Blog.
>
> To track or report an issue visit our Github page.
>
> ### Fixed
>
> - DrvFs is now case sensitive when running in Bash on Ubuntu on Windows.
> - Users may case.txt and CASE.TXT on their /mnt/c drives
> - Case sensitivity is only supported within Bash on Ubuntu on Windows. When outside of Bash NTFS will report the files correctly, but unexpected behavior may occur interacting with the files from Windows.
> - The root of each volume (i.e. /mnt/c) is not case sensitive
> - More information on handling these files in Windows can be found [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/100625).

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/release-notes#build-14361

Comment: New information that applies since Build 17704: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/improved-per-directory-case-sensitivity-support-in-wsl/