# Is UDF an ok substitute for ext3?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, format, ext3, udf

I'm thinking of doing the UDF thing to share files between windows and linux.

Is UDF a viable option for /home
Is UDF a viable option for /
Can windows XP correctly read sparse files I created in linux from UDF

As long as it doesn't break things I was going to rsync my ext3 backup drive over to UDF so I can see it in windows is this reliable?

Comment: Why not just use NTFS?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/39942/using-udf-on-a-usb-flash-drive

Comment: Should be closed as a duplicate of https://superuser.com/questions/45130/cross-platform-file-system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will be fine with windows 7, not so much with XP. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Disk_Format#Table_of_operating_systems) for more details.

Comment: What's worse is that I've never found an acceptable driver allowing for writing to UDF-formatted external HDs for XP.  Otherwise it'd be awesome.

Comment: Wikidia lists two (in the note section for XP)

Comment: Is 2.0 ok for xp if you only want read only? .. no sparse that's a big thumbs down for me.

Comment: Ok so vista and up is good. Now I just want to know if I can happily rsync my ext3 drive to it.

Comment: @soandos: I know DLA doesn't work, and I'm pretty sure that InCD doesn't.  See [here](http://superuser.com/questions/150864/driver-for-writing-to-udf-partitions-from-windows-xp/180096#180096) for more info.  (I'd forgotten about WriteUDF.)

Comment: I dont know any more, sorry.