# "Correct" way of UDF formatting a USB drive

Tags: usb-flash-drive, formatting, udf

I managed to UDF format my USB drive following the instructions in [Using UDF on a USB flash drive](https://superuser.com/questions/39942/using-udf-on-a-usb-flash-drive). Later, I came by [this post](http://wiki.laptop.org/go/How_to_Damage_a_FLASH_Storage_Device) and I began to doubt...

Could anyone explain which would be the "best" way of UDF formatting a USB drive taking into account both the question and the link provided? (I'm assuming that the link is trustworthy, but could be mistaken.)

Additionally: the linked question talks about zeroing the first sectors of the USB drive, I usually just go:

```
cp /dev/zero > /dev/sdX
```

and `Ctrl+C` my way out of it... does anyone know exactly how many bytes should be zeroed? (a snippet would be nice too :) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should zero at least 2048 bytes because UDF needs the first 2K area.

Comment: To be more precise: this first zone WILL NOT be erased by UDF.
(This zone is intentionnally left as-is, so it can be used to store, e.g.: bootloaders. Like on bootable DVDs. And UDF-as-a-USB-stick-format also use this zone for a special partition table)


If you format a USB stick with mkudffs, whatever was in those 2048 bytes will still be around to confuse your OS.
If there was a FAT32 partition there instead, there will still be enough of it left in the "bootloader area" of UDF so an OS might see it, and think that this is a FAT32 partition.