# Default partition for brand new SD card

Tags: partitioning, sd-card, micro-sd-card, sdhc

I have SanDisk microSDHC (class 4-16GB) card, which doesn't work now in my car after formatting in NTFS. I would like to change to default partition type. What is default partition type in brand new SD cards, which will work on most appliances?

Comment: Look up the specs for your car stereo, but the odds are you need it in Fat32.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should I format USB sticks and SD cards to FAT, FAT32, exFAT or NTFS? (Windows files, live Linux distors)](http://superuser.com/questions/533449/should-i-format-usb-sticks-and-sd-cards-to-fat-fat32-exfat-or-ntfs-windows-f)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:

Most embedded or mobile devices will only works with fat32.

Also, be careful about what kind of cards your device may accept, SDXC won't work on SDHC readers, on same even goes for both on classic SD card reader. It only depdens on how old your car or media player are.