# Unable to format a Pendrive (UDF)-TrusCont Protected

Tags: usb-flash-drive, formatting, usb-storage, write-protect

I received a Pendrive from my coaching classes loaded with notes and videos. The content in the Pendrive is protected and now the content has expired. I am unable to view the content any more and it's a 32 GB which is full and cannot be used.

I am unable to format the Pendrive. I am not able to find a format/delete option.

[image]

No format option and there is no delete option for files in the Pendrive.

Some things I tried-

- Command Line (DiskPart)
  Pendrive was not listed in the Disk List.
- Tools like-Kingston formatting tool and Apacer Repair Tool
  (didn't show any disk)

Is there any way by which I could reuse the Pendrive?

Is the UDF format causing the problem?

Also some kind of TrusCont Protection Tool is present in the Pendrive. Please help me. I have two such Pendrives and I would like to use it instead of throwing it away.

Answer (score 0):

The windows disk manager has many fails. I reccomend you something more powerfull like [AOMEI Partition Manager](http://www.disk-partition.com/free-partition-manager.html).

If it doesnt work you could try to format the USB from linux.

Comment: Mine is windows 10 and what I am trying is something very basic and already tried out some well known tools. I will have to disable the TrusCont protection somehow.

Comment: Also Disk Manager shows no partition options for the Pendrive.

Comment: Try [this](http://superuser.com/questions/726743/how-to-format-a-flash-drive-as-udf-in-windows-7)

Comment: That's something different. My pendrive is not even recognized on the command line. It is being hidden by TrusCont.